# How to schedule a job generating report with JasperServer rest api with "Run Immediate" option

Tags: rest, jasperserver

I'm trying to find out how to set all options of scheduling report in JasperServer with REST API.

I found that I can set simple trigger with XML

```
<simpleTrigger>
  <startDate>2020-08-10 16:26</startDate>
  <startType>2</startType>
  <timezone>Europe/Warsaw</timezone>
  <occurrenceCount>1</occurrenceCount>
  <recurrenceInterval>1</recurrenceInterval>
  <recurrenceIntervalUnit>DAY</recurrenceIntervalUnit>
</simpleTrigger>
```

and i know how to configure it to schedule it every 2 days for example

Then we have calendar trigger

```
<calendarTrigger>
    <startDate>2020-08-20 00:00</startDate>
    <startType>2</startType>
    <timezone>Europe/Warsaw</timezone>
    <daysType>MONTH</daysType>
    <hours>0</hours>
    <minutes>0</minutes>
    <monthDays>1,2</monthDays>
    <months>
        <month>1</month>
        <month>2</month>
    </months>
</calendarTrigger>
```

When we use JasperServer WebUI we can set "Immediately" start option.
I can't find how to set that option with REST API. Is there a list of all options somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `startdate` to `null` and `startType` to 1 (now)

```
"trigger": {
    "simpleTrigger": {
        "endDate": null,
        "occurrenceCount": 1,
        "recurrenceInterval": null,
        "recurrenceIntervalUnit": null,
        "startDate": null,
        "startType": 1,
        "timezone": "Europe/Warsaw"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) this is working exactly how I wanted. Do you know any documentation with specification of all available options ?

Comment: I looked into official documentation but couldn't find there. So I had to go to source code [JRS Git repo](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports-server-ce/blob/master/jasperserver-api-impl/engine/src/main/java/com/jaspersoft/jasperserver/api/engine/scheduling/quartz/ReportJobsQuartzScheduler.java)

Comment: I also captured REST communication between the browser and JRS just to confirm the undocumented behavior.

Comment: is there a option to know when jasper finished generating file?